# How to data bind a WorkflowDesigner workflow definition to a MVVM View model in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to use the built-in data binding to load and save workflow definitions to a database using the rehosted workflowdesigner class, WPF and MVVM. My xaml.cs file programatically creates the workflow designer and sets the WorkflowDEsigner.View to a Tab Content control.

I'm looking for a way to data bind the a property of the workflow designer to my view model object. That way, when the user creates a workflow definition and hits save, my viewmodel will (via databinding) have the string representation of the workflow definition so that it can be persisted to a database. And when a user clicks Load, a workflow definition will be queried from the database, and hydrated into the MVVM object and then databound to the workflowdesigner for display.

The WorkflowDesigner.Text property doesn't get populated until WorkflowDesigner.Save() is called which saves the definition to a file. I definitely don't want to do that.

Currently I'm rolling my own by hooking the WorkflowDesigner.ModelChanged event and in that event handler, get the text and then manually set the view model. Is there a pure databinding way to accomplish this?

//initialization of the designer

```
  m_objWFWorkerDesigner = new WorkflowDesigner();
  m_objWFWorkerDesigner.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerConfigurationService>().AnnotationEnabled = true;
  m_objWFWorkerDesigner.Context.Services.GetService<DesignerConfigurationService>().TargetFrameworkName = new
              System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName(".NET Framework", new Version(4, 5));
  m_objWFWorkerDesigner.Load(new System.Activities.ActivityBuilder());
  m_objWFWorkerDesigner.ModelChanged += m_objWFWorkerDesigner_ModelChanged;    


void m_objWFWorkerDesigner_ModelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ((RehostedWorkflowDesignerVM)this.DataContext).WorkerWorkflow = GetActivityString(sender);
}

private static string GetActivityString(object sender)
{
  ActivityBuilder activityBuilder = (ActivityBuilder)((WorkflowDesigner)sender).Context.Services.GetService<ModelTreeManager>().Root.GetCurrentValue();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
  XamlWriter xw = ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderWriter(new XamlXmlWriter(tw, new XamlSchemaContext()));
  XamlServices.Save(xw, activityBuilder);
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`WorkflowDesigner` and its surrounding controls (toolbox, properties editor, etc.) are not MVVM-friendly so you won't be able to bind data to them the proper way.

What I've done in [FlowStudio](https://flowstudio.codeplex.com/) was to encapsulate those controls inside a truly WPF control which uses dependency properties to enable databinding through XAML.

I've started by doing it to ToolboxControl. You can check it [here](https://flowstudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#FlowStudio/View/Toolbox.cs).